# Set radio button value equal to text in specific table row

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table which I populate with data from server using php. Next, I add a cell for each row of data and put a radio button in that cell. I do it with the following code:

```
  <script>
  var table=document.getElementById("dataTables-1");
  table.createTHead()

  var cell;
  var row;

  for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length-1;i++){
      row=table.rows[i];
      cell=row.insertCell(0);
      cell.innerHTML="<?php echo '<input type=' . "'radio'" . ' name=' . "'radio'" . '>' ?>"
  }
  </script>
```

What I need to do is add value property to the radio button node, that would equal the innerHTML of cell in that table, in the same row.

My aim is to create a table in which user selects a table row (using radio button) and then presses the button below the table which has action="some_other_page.php" and keep the $_POST["radio"] (value taken from one of the columns, in the row selected by user) to process it further.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
cell.innerHTML="<?php echo '<input type=' . "'radio'" . ' name=' . "'radio'" . '>' ?>"
```

to this :

```
cell.innerHTML="<?php echo '<input type=' . "'radio'" . ' name=' . "'radio'" . 'value=' .  "$valueOfInnerHTMLOfTable" . '>' ?>"
```

Where `$valueOfInnerHTMLOfTable` is the value you want to set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I get $valueOfInnerHTMLOfTable?

Comment: That's the value you want to set the radio button to